# How can I display sensor value from AWS DynamoDB to my front-end?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-iot, aws-datastore

I am building an android IoT app using AWS Amplify and DynamoDB. I have an ESP32 here that publishes data the sensor data to a topic I created a rule that would store it to separate DynamoDB columns.

My code below is to sort the data in descending order according to the timestamp and return a query with a limit of 1. It works for the first time, but I noticed it returns the same item even if the database is already updated or the item is no longer in the table. I have read about DynamoDB Stream, Lambda, and IoT Device Shadow but I am new to AWS and I'm confused on which service or what method works best and is not too complex for me.

This is my code to retrieve data:

```
    public void readById() {

        Amplify.DataStore.query(
                myModel.class,
                Where.sorted(myModel.ID.descending()).paginated(Page.startingAt(0).withLimit(1)),

                items -> {
                    while (items.hasNext()) {
                        mModel item = items.next();
                        retrievedId = item.getId();

                        Log.i("Amplify", "Id " + item.getId());
                    }

                },
                failure -> Log.e("Amplify", "Could not query DataStore", failure)
        );
    }
```

Any input is appreaciated!

Comment: Where are you sorting by descending timestamp?

Comment: @jarmod the primary key

Comment: Are you saying that your table has a simple (non-composite) primary key comprising partition key only and that partition key is called ID and it contains a timestamp?

Comment: @jarmod Yes, I was not able to set a sort key since the table was auto-generated when initialized amplify. Apologies if I did things wrong and thanks for the response

Comment: You can't retrieve the 'latest' item in that case, unless you also has a GSI on that ID attribute. Typically the timestamp would be the range key on the table and the partition key would be something suitable like a device ID or, if there is no sensible partition, then it would be a fixed value (which is not great for partitioning, of course). There is no way to scan in reverse, for example. The typical way to get the latest item is for the items to have the same partition key and to be sorted on their range key which needs to be, or end with, a timestamp, then issue a query.

Comment: So you're saying I need to create a GSI and store the timestamp in it, and use it to sort the values instead?

Comment: Sorting is done on sort (aka range) keys, not on partition (aka hash) keys, so you have no choice but to do this by storing the timestamp (or a prefix + timestamp) as a range key. If you can't do this in a composite primary key on the table then you have to do it in a GSI. If all you care about is the timestamp, then the hash key of that GSI would be a fixed value (e.g. a constant string value of "index").